# How to get all the values from an search result

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elastic Search. Is there any way to get all the search results for a search keyword? Elastic Search is limited to 10 or else we can set the size but we need to get the size??

Comment: I would recoment to use scroll search for fetching all records(like paging). http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html

Answer (score 16):

Yes, the default number of search results is 10.

You need to [set the `size` parameter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size.html) on the query.

I don't think you an say "all results", though, there must always be a size limit.

Comment: @raagavan: Total size of what?

Comment: @skaffman see if i search an keyword `example` if it is in 200 document i need to display the 200 results ..

Comment: is there is any way to make field collapase like solr `http://blog.jteam.nl/2009/10/20/result-grouping-field-collapsing-with-solr/`

Comment: @raagavan no. but you could look into chield parent stuff: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/has-child-filter.html

Comment: @raagavan if you need allways all documents (why would you??) consider scan search: http://www.elasticsearch.org/blog/2011/03/24/new-search-types.html

Comment: what's the max accepted value for size? can't find it in the docs and the c# int.MaxValue fails with brio.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the JAVA API you can simple get the total hit number from the SearchResponse

```
SearchRequestBuilder srb = ..
SearchResponse sr = srb.execute().actionGet();
long totalHits = sr.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in couple of steps using some code

1. Fix a size say `1000` and get all 1000 records.
2. Identify from `hits.total` whether size is smaller than 1000. (if small then you got all the records :) )
3. Otherwise use [from and size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) to provide `1001` in from and `total` as size from previous query to get full result.