# Get all results of elasticsearch without pagination

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

Elastic-search has `from/size` parameter and this `size` is 10 by default. How to get all the results without pagination?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get all the values from an search result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990598/how-to-get-all-the-values-from-an-search-result)

Answer (score 3):

first get count of results . you can get it by count api. the put n into following method of QueryBuilder.

```
CountResponse response = client.prepareCount("test")
    .setQuery(termQuery("_type", "type1"))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

then call

```
n=response.getCount();
```

you can use setSize(n).

for non java use like this curl request.

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_count' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}'
```

more on this can be found on this link.
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html

Comment: You are right, but there must be a single step solution to this like `size=all` or `size=none`.

Comment: I havn't encountered such thing till now.